# Why the Lemma below is true even if the measure $\mu$ is infinite?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

[image]

A Bartle exercise proposes to show that lemma 8.8 is true even if the measure $\mu$ is infinite. What I can not see is any difference between the proof of lemma 8.8 and the solution for exercise. Can someone explain to me if it has any difference?

Comment: I can't observe the given condition "μ and λ are finite" is used in the proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: the given argument works without assuming $\mu$ is finite.  The only place that such finiteness might be used would be to conclude that$$\mu\left(\bigcap F_n\right)=\lim\mu(F_n).$$  However, since we know $\mu(F_1)<1/2$ is finite, this equation is valid even without knowing that $\mu$ is a finite measure.

(On the other hand, the assumption that $\lambda$ is finite is crucial to the argument, since we do not know that $\lambda(F_n)$ is finite for any $n$.  Indeed, the result is not true without some kind of finiteness assumption on $\lambda$.  For instance, let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\lambda(A)=0$ if $\mu(A)=0$ and $\lambda(A)=\infty$ if $\mu(A)>0$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I was just thinking about it, that $\mu(F_1)<1/2$ being finite guarantees the result. coincidentally I am solving an exercise that says that the counterexample you gave is an infinite measure.